# Werewolf movie where the chief clue is enhanced senses

Tags: story-identification, movie, werewolf

I haven't watched this movie, but heard this from a friend and it interests me, so I'm here to ask.

- Male lead gets wounded by a wolf on the night of a full moon, and he doesn't pay much attention to the wound. After this the male lead's sense of smell is enhanced a lot.
- When the male lead and female lead are talking through the phone, the male lead complains to the female lead about making too much noise tidying her hair. (His sense of hearing was also enhanced a lot).
- The male lead once handcuffed himself in the bed at night, to constrain himself from turning into a werewolf and hurting someone.
- Around the end of the movie, the male lead fights with another werewolf to protect the female lead. The female lead is rescued and the male lead turns into a werewolf and runs away. In a conversation with the police, the female lead said her hearing is so sensitive that she knows what is happening a mile away. (This hints she is becoming a werewolf.)

*These descriptions are not entirely accurate as they were rephrased and translated.*

Answer (score 22, accepted):

I believe this might be the movie [Wolf](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wolf_(1994_film)) with Jack Nicholson, Michelle Pfeiffer & James Spader.

> Male lead gets wounded by a wolf on the night of a full moon, and he
> doesn't pay much attention to the wound. After this the male lead's
> sense of smell is enhanced a lot.

Nicholsons character is bitten by a wolf his car strikes while driving at night in Vermont.

> The male lead once handcuffed himself in the bed at night, to constrain himself from turning into a werewolf and hurting someone.

He cuffs himself to a radiator.

> Around the end of the movie, the male lead fights with another
> werewolf to protect the female lead. The female lead is rescued and
> the male lead turns into a werewolf and runs away. In a conversation
> with the police, the female lead said her hearing is so sensitive that
> she knows what is happening a mile away. (This hints she is becoming a
> werewolf.)

Rather than hear things a long way off, she shows hightened senses by smelling alcohol on the policeman's breath from some distance away.

> Laura herself shows heightened senses when the police arrive; telling
> Bridger that she can smell vodka on his breath before taking her leave

I enjoyed the movie myself, but remember being confused, it's the first movie I saw where the characters were obtusely genre blind - *danger TV Tropes link* - [genre blind](https://tvtropes.org/pmwiki/pmwiki.php/Main/GenreBlindness)

Answer (score 18):

This is [*Wolf*](https://www.imdb.com/title/tt0111742/) (1994) starring Jack Nicholson, Michelle Pfeiffer and James Spader.

Selectively quoting from the synopses on [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wolf_(1994_film)#Plot) and [IMDb](https://www.imdb.com/title/tt0111742/plotsummary#synopsis):

Bitten by a wolf:

> Will Randall [Nicholson] is **bitten by a black wolf** he accidentally struck while driving home in Vermont.

[image: Will (Jack Nicholson) checks out a wolf he hit with his car.]

Enhanced sense of smell:

> Will [...] that Stewart is having an affair with his wife Charlotte, after **he smells Stewart's scent** on her clothes.

Handcuffed himself in the bed at night:

> He **cuffs himself to a radiator** in his hotel room, but Laura arrives and downplays his belief that he is werewolf.

Complains to the female lead about making too much noise tidying her hair:

> WILL: And finish drying. The sound of that towel is driving me crazy.
>
> LAURA: Are you telling me that you hear what I'm doing over the phone?

Will fights another werewolf to protect the female lead:

> After killing two guards at the estate, Stewart [Spader] corners Laura [Pfeiffer] in the barn with the intention to rape her, but Will intervenes after discarding the amulet restraining him and **the two fight**

[image: Stewart (Spader), partially transformed to a wolf, assaults Laura (Pfeiffer) in the barn]

This hints she is becoming a werewolf:

> Minutes later, **Laura herself shows heightened senses** when the police arrive; telling Bridger that she can smell vodka on his breath before taking her leave. The final scene is a close-up of her face and of Will finally turning into a full wolf howling for Laura. Then it goes back to **Laura's face as her eyes become wolf-like**, hinting that she herself is transforming into a werewolf.

[image: Image of Laura's head, with yellow eyes showing she is becoming a werewolf]

Comment: +1 You got in just before me :)

Comment: I think you beat me, actually; you show up first in "time order."  I can delete my answer, but if you want to copy the pictures first I'll give you a chance.

Comment: Leave them both dude, your answer is better quality :)